# Django equivalent of New Relic RPM for Rails?

Tags: python, django

Does Django have anything equivalent to the New Relic RPM performance monitoring app for Rails (http://www.newrelic.com/)?

Looking to do an app in Django, but would really like to be able to use something like New Relic for monitoring performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None that I'm aware. django-debug-toolbar is a fairly popular app which can provide you with performance info for a particular page, but feature-wise it doesn't even come close to what the New Relic demo shows (I have no experience with NR/RoR myself).

Answer (score 7):

YES!  We (New Relic) just announced our Python agent at DjangoCon this week. Sign up at newrelic.com and enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry that New Relic doesn't support Python web apps (and therefore Django) at this time, but it is definitely something we are looking at for the long term roadmap.  It may be too late for your current requirements, but stay tuned as we continue to build out our footprint.  Good luck!

Lew Cirne
Founder and CEO
New Relic